# Modifier the Log level about Jake Wharton's Hugo

Tags: hugo, hugo-logging

As we know !Hugo's ***default log level is verbose***.

In practice,verbose log is too Verbose for me.It show to much information to screen so that developer can not fetch the main Info.

My Question is if there had any method to ***change Hugo's log level(verbose)*** to other log level(e.g debug ,info ,error,wtf )

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hugo's default log level is not verbose. To *make* it verbose, use `--version` or `-v`. To make it quiet, use `--quiet`.